# Install plugin on multiple EC2 instance on AWS

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

I'm planning to install a plugin on multiple AWS ec2 Linux instances. Is there a PowerShell or bash script where I can point to a plugin path and run a command to install with a list of server detail with ssh access.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install and configure the plugin for **new instances** or your launch template/configuration used in **AutoScaling Group**, you would normally use [UserData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) for that:

> When you launch an instance in Amazon EC2, you have the option of passing user data to the instance that can be used to perform common automated **configuration tasks and even run scripts** after the instance starts.

How to do it on Windows is explained in the following AWS docs:

- [Running commands on your Windows instance at launch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install software on a large number of instances at the same time take a look at [run commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) within systems manager.

You can use the `AWS-RunPowerShellScript` document to specify powershell commands. During execution you can specify a list of instance ids to run this command against.

More information available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/walkthrough-powershell.html).